# Select different value from different tag for xpath

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to get xpath for this element:
[image]

I am expecting the output should be:

> Brands
>   Lazada

in one query. not in multiple query.

The best I found so far is:

> //li[text()='Brands'] and //em[text()='Lazada']

but this return

> 1

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like `"node and node"` should return boolean (`true` in case both nodes found and `false` if at least one not found). Your tool might return `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`)

To get required text you can try

```
normalize-space(//ul[@id="ui-id-1"])
```

or

```
concat(//ul[@id="ui-id-1"]/li[1]/text(), " ", //ul[@id="ui-id-1"]//em/text())
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did try the first one which return invalid xpath expression and the second one didnt return both text.

Comment: Check updated answer. Does it work? You also might specify the tool you use and how exactly you use `XPath`

Comment: I am using xpath helper to check. concat return both value but is there any way to return both without using concat? using direct xpath as `//li[text()='Brands'] and //em[text()='Lazada']`

Comment: `concat()` is a function to return couple of text nodes as a single string. This seem to be exactly what you need. You might also try `//ul[@id="ui-id-1"]/li[1]/text() | //ul[@id="ui-id-1"]//em/text()`, but in this case you'll get `Brands` and `Lazada` as two separate values. `and` operator in `XPath` might be used in logical expressions only